# JavaScript function returns empty string when a value is expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There's probably an obvious mistake somewhere, but I just can't out find what's wrong.

I'm trying to retrieve data from an api, and use the js-function below to get it. If I do an alert(key) on the data inside the $.get-function, it alerts the correct data.

```
function getApiKey(company, password) {
    var url = "http://myapi.com/" +company+ "?password=" +password;
    var key = "";

    $.get(url).done(function(data) {
        key = data;
        //alert(key) returns the correct data
    });

    return key;
}
```

However, I need to use the function in a different file, and that's where it doesn't work. When I do

```
    var key = getApiKey("company", "password");
    alert(key);
```

key is empty.

Comment: You can't do it like that. [This answer explains why and shows some solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $.get command is asynchronous, meaning that your function returns key with its initial value of "", then later when the async callback fires, it runs key=data.

You should read up on asynchronous behaviour in javascript - for a solution, you'll need some way to get the data back to the place of the call asynchronously. One such option is a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).